# ASP.NET MVC - Nesting Routes / Controllers

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have an ASP.NET MVC app. I have seen similar question asked. However, I haven't found a good answer. Essentially, I want to use the following routes:

```
/admin/users
/admin/users/create
/admin/users/[someId]
/admin/roles
/admin/roles/create
/admin/roles/[someId]
```

I have the following file structure:

```
/Controllers
  AdminController.cs
  /Admin
    UsersController.cs
    RolesController.cs
/Views
  /Admin
    Index.cshtml
    /Users
      Index.cshtml
      Detail.cshtml
      Create.cshtml
    /Roles
      Index.cshtml
      Create.cshtml
      Detail.cshtml
```

When I run my app, I just get `The resource cannot be found.`

What am I doing wrong? I set breakpoints, but none of them are being hit. It's like the routes aren't mapping to the controllers. I'm not sure what I need to do though.

Comment: Your file structure doesn't really matter. Your routes matter, but you haven't included them in your question.

Comment: By default you can find your RouteConfig.cs in the App_Start Folder. Maybe show add it to your question.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You do not need to create sub folders for this to work. Just have 2 controllers(`UsersController` and `RolesController`)  and you can use attribute routing to define the custom routing pattern you want.

Assuming you have attribute routing enabled

```
public class UsersController : Controller
{
  [Route("admin/users")]
  public ActionResult Index()  { // to do : Return something }

  [Route("admin/users/create")]
  public ActionResult Create()  { // to do : Return something }

  [Route("admin/users/{id}")]
  public ActionResult View(int id)  { // to do : Return something }    
}
```

Or you can do the `RoutePrefix` on the controller level.

```
[RoutePrefix("admin/users")]
public class UsersController : Controller
{
  [Route("")]
  public ActionResult Index()  { // to do : Return something }

  [Route("create")]
  public ActionResult Create()  { // to do : Return something }

  [Route("{id}")]
  public ActionResult View(int id)  { // to do : Return something }    
}
```

You can do the samething for the RolesControllers as well.

You can enable attribute routing in the `RegisterRoutes` method in `RouteConfig.cs` file.

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{            
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
    routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes(); //This line enables attribute routing 
   //Existing default Route definition goes here
}
```

You may also consider creating an "Admin" area and put your controllers inside that. [Areas](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee671793(v=vs.100).aspx) are the right solution if you want to logically group similar functionality.

If you do not prefer attribute routing ( why not ?) , you an define these custom route patterns in your RouteConfig. **The order in you define the route matters.So make sure you define your specific routes before the default generic one**.

Comment: Is there a way for me to use sub folders? I will have a lot of controllers under the admin route. That's one reason I want to use sub folders.

Comment: You can use sub folders.As long as your class names ends with `Controller`, It will be picked up.  If you want to logically group funcionality/controllers, consider creating an Admin Area.

Answer (score 1):

You can also override your route tables by decorating your action methods with the [RouteAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.routeattribute(v=vs.118).aspx) class.

For example:

```
class AdminController
{
    [Route("/admin/users/create")]
    public ViewResult CreateUser()
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

This has the advantage of separating the method name from the url component.

You can also route multiple URLs to a single method:

```
class AdminController
{
    [Route("/admin/users/{someId:guid}")]
    [Route("/admin/users/{someId:guid}/details")]
    public ViewResult UserDetails(Guid someID)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

As mason said, the file structure isn't important in MVC routing.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use convention (folder) based routing, you could use [MvcCodeRouting](http://mvccoderouting.codeplex.com/) to do exactly what you have specified here. It uses namespaces by default, so when you add controllers in a hierarchy, it will generate routes in the same hierarchy automatically. No need to apply the `[Route]` attribute everywhere and setup your routes manually.